# UITableView - Not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set up `tableview` many times but don't why is not it showing anything. I have added a `tableview` on my `storyboard` file, added reference on `ViewController` file and set `datasource` and `delegate` on `storyboard`. on `viewDidLoad` registered the cell and finally added `reusableIdentifier` on `TableViewCell`. Here is my code with details configuration :

```
import UIKit

struct ViewControllerConstants {
    static let kCellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"
    static let kNibName = "TableViewCell"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cellImageNames : [String] = ["image1","image2","image3","image4","image5","image6"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: ViewControllerConstants.kNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: ViewControllerConstants.kCellIdentifier)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellImageNames.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ViewControllerConstants.kCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {

            cell.contentImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: cellImageNames[indexPath.row])
            return cell

        }



        return UITableViewCell.init()

    }


}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

[image: TableView Custom Cells]

[image: TableView Custom Cell 2]

[image: Storyboard References details]

Comment: first check tableView height if it is zero then then table will not display, second cell heights

Comment: Please remove `self.tableView.register...`. Should be unnecessary as you have correctly specified the cell’s reuse identifier in the storyboard. After that, put breakpoints into the datasource functions to check if the are called at all. Did you connect the cell’s outlets?

Comment: Please share the whole project

Comment: You does not set any height in datasource don't know why

Comment: DataSource method are called and not null @ Tom E

Comment: Table view constraints are top,bottom,leading,trailing all equals to zero with super view @ Pravin Tate

Comment: It's was the height of the cell that causes this problem. Thanks Pravin Tate

Comment: Look at ` return UITableViewCell.init()` put a break point there, and see if it ever stops there. Also, override the HeightForRow Delegate method, and return the desired height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** Cell height was not defined on code. So it was creating cell with 0 height value .

**Solution:** Need to specify height of each row as below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove identifiers for cells in storyboard.

Comment: When using a reuse identifier in the storyboard there‘s no need to register the cell in code.

Comment: I need to register the cell otherwise it will show this error .. """erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TableViewCellID - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'